# Request-Reply with several following queues

Tags: java, apache-camel, jms

I have multiple sequential queues in InOut pattern, each queue leads to one Camel processor.
If a processor takes too much time for a treatment, I would like that the request-reply detects a timeout and send a *ExchangeTimedOutException*.
The timeout with *CamelJmsRequestTimeout* works but only for the first queue.

Example,
If I have this:

```
q1 -> p1 -> q2 -> p2 ->  q3 -> p3
```

q1 *CamelJmsRequestTimeout* is for example 5s. If each processor take 3s (I simulate latency in processor with sleep()), I will have a timeout at p2 cause the total time is 6s. Why the reply to q1 is not sent after p1 instead, manifestly, after p3?

This is an example code:

```
from("jms:queue:q1")
        .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
        .setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, constant("5000"))
        .process("p1")
        .to("jms:queue:q2");

from("jms:queue:q2")
        .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
        .setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, constant("5000"))
        .process("p2")
        .to("jms:queue:q3");

from("jms:queue:q3")
        .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOut)
        .setHeader(JmsConstants.JMS_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, constant("5000"))
        .process("p3");
```

Is my design possible? If yes, which option should I use?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
2019-08-07 09:45:02,718 [main] INFO  SpringCamelContext  - Apache Camel 2.21.0 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 1.152 seconds
2019-08-07 09:45:05,973 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[q1]] INFO  input  - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: String, Body: stuff in the body]
2019-08-07 09:45:09,022 [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - JmsConsumer[q2]] INFO  input  - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: String, Body: stuff in the body]
2019-08-07 09:45:11,991 [Camel (camel-1) thread #25 - JmsReplyManagerOnTimeout[q2]] WARN  TemporaryQueueReplyManager  - Timeout occurred after 5000 millis waiting for reply message with correlationID [Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-2] on destination temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:20:1. Setting ExchangeTimedOutException on (MessageId: ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:19:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-1) and continue routing.
2019-08-07 09:45:11,996 [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - JmsConsumer[q1]] WARN  EndpointMessageListener  - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-2 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:20:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-1]]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-2 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:20:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-1]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1830)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback.done(EndpointMessageListener.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1057)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-2 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:20:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:170)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap$1.run(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
2019-08-07 09:45:11,997 [Camel (camel-1) thread #25 - JmsReplyManagerOnTimeout[q2]] ERROR DefaultErrorHandler  - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:19:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-1). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-2 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:20:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-1]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [jms://queue:q1                                                                ] [      9051]
[route1            ] [setExchangePattern] [setExchangePattern[InOut]                                                     ] [         6]
[route1            ] [setHeader1        ] [setHeader[CamelJmsRequestTimeout]                                             ] [         0]
[route1            ] [process1          ] [Processor@0x39652a30                                                          ] [      3001]
[route1            ] [to1               ] [log:input                                                                     ] [         4]
[route1            ] [to2               ] [jms:queue:q2                                                                  ] [      6019]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-2 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:20:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-1]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:170)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap$1.run(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-08-07 09:45:12,062 [Camel (camel-1) thread #3 - JmsConsumer[q3]] INFO  input  - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: String, Body: stuff in the body]
2019-08-07 09:45:12,093 [Camel (camel-1) thread #4 - JmsConsumer[q4]] INFO  input  - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOnly, BodyType: String, Body: stuff in the body]
2019-08-07 09:45:15,034 [Camel (camel-1) thread #28 - JmsReplyManagerOnTimeout[q3]] WARN  TemporaryQueueReplyManager  - Timeout occurred after 5000 millis waiting for reply message with correlationID [Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-4] on destination temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:21:1. Setting ExchangeTimedOutException on (MessageId: ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:1:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-3) and continue routing.
2019-08-07 09:45:15,038 [Camel (camel-1) thread #2 - JmsConsumer[q2]] WARN  EndpointMessageListener  - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-4 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:21:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-3]]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-4 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:21:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-3]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1830)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback.done(EndpointMessageListener.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1057)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-4 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:21:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:170)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap$1.run(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
2019-08-07 09:45:15,039 [Camel (camel-1) thread #28 - JmsReplyManagerOnTimeout[q3]] ERROR DefaultErrorHandler  - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:1:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-3). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-4 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:21:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-3]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route2            ] [route2            ] [jms://queue:q2                                                                ] [      9017]
[route2            ] [setExchangePattern] [setExchangePattern[InOut]                                                     ] [         0]
[route2            ] [setHeader2        ] [setHeader[CamelJmsRequestTimeout]                                             ] [         0]
[route2            ] [process2          ] [Processor@0x5763a655                                                          ] [      3001]
[route2            ] [to3               ] [log:input                                                                     ] [         2]
[route2            ] [to4               ] [jms:queue:q3                                                                  ] [      6012]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-4 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:21:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:170)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap$1.run(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-08-07 09:45:18,071 [Camel (camel-1) thread #29 - JmsReplyManagerOnTimeout[q4]] WARN  TemporaryQueueReplyManager  - Timeout occurred after 5000 millis waiting for reply message with correlationID [Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-6] on destination temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:22:1. Setting ExchangeTimedOutException on (MessageId: ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:2:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-5) and continue routing.
2019-08-07 09:45:18,072 [Camel (camel-1) thread #3 - JmsConsumer[q3]] WARN  EndpointMessageListener  - Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException - org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-6 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:22:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-5]]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-6 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:22:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-5]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1830)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback.done(EndpointMessageListener.java:196)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:719)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:679)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1168)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1160)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1057)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-6 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:22:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:170)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap$1.run(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    ... 3 more
2019-08-07 09:45:18,073 [Camel (camel-1) thread #29 - JmsReplyManagerOnTimeout[q4]] ERROR DefaultErrorHandler  - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:2:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-5). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-6 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:22:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-5]

Message History
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId          Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route3            ] [route3            ] [jms://queue:q3                                                                ] [      9010]
[route3            ] [setExchangePattern] [setExchangePattern[InOut]                                                     ] [         0]
[route3            ] [setHeader3        ] [setHeader[CamelJmsRequestTimeout]                                             ] [         0]
[route3            ] [process3          ] [Processor@0x40c8067                                                           ] [      3000]
[route3            ] [to5               ] [log:input                                                                     ] [         0]
[route3            ] [to6               ] [jms:queue:q4                                                                  ] [      6009]

Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 5000 millis due reply message with correlationID: Camel-ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-6 not received on destination: temp-queue://ID:ITEM-S69138-55901-1565163899733-4:22:1. Exchange[ID-ITEM-S69138-1565163898705-0-5]
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.ReplyManagerSupport.processReply(ReplyManagerSupport.java:170)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.onTimeout(TemporaryQueueReplyHandler.java:62)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.reply.CorrelationTimeoutMap$1.run(CorrelationTimeoutMap.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. You get an `ExchangeTimedOutException` on `q1` which is correct because the processing takes more than 5 seconds. What do you mean with "reply" that is sent too late?

Comment: According to my example, _CamelJmsRequestTimeout_ is set to 5s, the processing time of a processor (px) is 3s.
I want to have a reply to q1 directly sent after processor p1. But the reply to q1 is sent after p3 processing. 
So, if each processor takes 3s, the timeout of q1 will appear when the processing will be in the p2 processing (after ~2s of p2 processing + 3sec of p1 processing = 5s)

Comment: This is the part I understand. What I don't understand is the sentence `Why the reply to q1 is not sent after p1 instead, manifestly, after p3?` What exactly is sent back after `p3`? The `ExchangeTimedOutException` or the processing result?

Comment: What is sent is the reply put in the temp queue (created automatically by camel) to acknowledge the data consumed by a queue.

Comment: edit: I added the result of an actual execution

Answer (score 1):

The important point here is that you do **3 individual JMS interactions**.

So, if you would have **no timeouts at all**, the sender would receive the answer after about 9 seconds on the answer queue it listens on. Because the sender does not know about the things behind q1, this would look like

```
Sender > q1 > listen on answer-q and wait > answer-message
```

When you set the timeout to 5 seconds at the sender, the request is discarded when the timeout is reached.

```
Sender > q1 > listen on answer-q > stop listening after 5 seconds
```

However, when the **sender stops listening** for the answer of q1, this **does not affect the other JMS interactions**! Every JMS producer starts the timeout when it sends the message.

The producer of the q1-route sends a message to q2 **about 3 seconds after it has received the message** from the sender. Because the processing from this point takes at least 6 seconds, it also runs into the timeout. So it also stops listening for an answer after 5 seconds.

The producer of the q2-route sends a message to q3 **about 3 seconds after it has received the message** from the q1-route and about 6 seconds after the sender has sent the initial message. Because the processing from this point takes about 3 seconds, it **will receive an answer** from q3.

It will then try to send this answer back to the producer of the q1-route, but this one already stopped listening. I assume this will fail, but I don't know the exact behavior of the temporary answer-queues.

To sum up the whole thing: **the final processing result will be computed, but because this takes too long it cannot be sent back to the sender**.

Comment: my lack of understanding is cause I basically thought that after each message consumption the reply was sent to the previous producer: `receives a message on a qx > process it > immediately reply to qx-reply queue`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Well, your current processing chain needs to be complete to compute the final result. Therefore it is not possible to immediately return a response that contains the result. You can of course immediately return an "acknowledge response" without a result and continue asynchronous. But then you can drop synchronous request/reply completely because this would be "standard asynchronous JMS" (no responses, acknowledge by the broker).